# No se muestra el html cuando lo llamo con javascript al momento de imprimir un PDF

Tags: javascript

estoy usando una librería jsPDF para hacer e imprimir un PDF, sin embargo, cuando lo ejecuto la pagina no descarga ningún archivo, solo se muestra el link para descargar.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>
```

```
<div id="testdiv" style="display: none">
<h1>hola</h1>

</div>
```

descargar

```
    function genPDF(){

        var doc = new jsPDF();

        doc.fromHTML($('#testdiv'), 20,20, {

            'widht':500
        });

        doc.save('test.pdf');


    }



</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si te muestra el link para descargar puedes usar la propiedad siguiente que te abre una nueva ventana visualizando el pdf

```
window.open(URL_FICHERO);
```

O puedes usar este codigo para que se descargue el archivo directamente

```
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = "display: none";
    a.href = URL_FICHERO;
    a.download = filename;
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```

Espero que te ayude!!